# how to relocate package inside jar for gradle dependencies

Tags: java, android, gradle

currently I am using a package call `a.jar`. Unfortunately that this jar includes a `com.example.b` package with some customized changes to code base inside `com.example.b`.

Now I want to have some latest cool features from `com.example.b` package in `b.jar` from github.

I think the best solution (not sure how it can be done) is to relocate latest `com.example.b` to `com.example.standalone.b` , so that the `a.jar` can still use its customized `com.exampl.b` source, while inside project I can use `com.example.standalone.b` package.

I did research for `shadow` plugin, but seems it rename package by package name globally, so that the package (`com.example.b`) in both jars (`a.jar` and `b.jar`) would be also renamed and have conflict.

May I know how to do this for specific jar, like below example?

```
implementation a.jar:1.0
implementation (b.jar:2.0) {
   rename 'com.example.b' to 'com.example.standalone.b'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally i managed to solve it by below configuration in goovy gradle.

```
configurations {
    relocateB // just define a separate configuration
}


task relocateB (type: ShadowJar) {
    def pkg = 'com.example.b' // lib to relocate
    relocate pkg, "com.example.standalone.b" // we want to relocate the above package
    configurations = [project.configurations.relocateB] // our configuration from above
    dependencies {
        // you must exclude below files in 'kotlin_module' and 'kotlin_builtins' extension, 
        // otherwise you won't be able to import `com.example.standalone.b` in kotlin files. 
        // This is a bug from Kotlin, consumed two days for me to solve. 
        // (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25709)
        exclude '**/*.kotlin_metadata'
        exclude '**/*.kotlin_module'
        exclude '**/*.kotlin_builtins'
    }
}


tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn relocateB
}



dependencies {
    ...
    relocateB ('com.example.b:2.2.3')
    api tasks.relocateB.outputs.files
    api 'com.example.a' // original package that won't be polluted
    ...
}
```

Comment: what does `relocateB ('com.example.b:2.2.3')` do?

Comment: @GeoffLangenderfer you need to add 'com.example.b:2.2.3' to configuration 'relocateB', so that 'relocateB' task knows which package to relocate.